# Add jplist script to Craft CMS

Tags: templating, jquery

I found this useful search, sort and filter script http://jplist.com, which I have added to my website. It works perfectly until I realize that when my database grow to the point it slow the page down. I am on the fence whether use Craft's `{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}` or jplist's data source to fetch the entries from the database?

Any suggestion what the best safest approach?